# How to send cache-control: no-cache from mobile?

Tags: caching, mobile, varnish

we're using Varnish for caching our pages, and it is configured to differentiate user-agent versions of pages.
So mobiles will have different version of page than desktop browser.

From a desktop browser, it's easy to send a "cache-control: no-cache" with CTRL+F5 shortcut.
It will enforce Varnish to refresh the page in its cache.

But how to do the same thing from a mobile, how do not have any CTRL key ??

Many thanks
Etienne

Answer (score 0):

As i know, just three options available on different browsers:

1. Slide down
2. Settings -> Refresh
3. Settings -> Privacy -> Clear cache (All/For this site only)

If 1 and 2 doesn't help you just make extra click to clear cache manually

**UPDATE:**
Ok I check safari and chrome [at this site](http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php): it seems like you cannot send `pragma: no-cache`, from browser, only programmatically via `meta` tags, so there is no way to do it

Comment: Ok, it will refresh local mobile cache, but will it send http header "cache-control: no-cache", as desktop browser with "CTRL+F5" do ?

Comment: I confirm, it doesn't work, it only clear the local cache and doesn't send any http header cache-control: no-cache. I've tested with android  and chrome remote debugging. :(

Comment: Tiny bookmarklet to add on your mobile bookmarks : `javascript:(function(){var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.open('GET', window.location.href);xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');xhr.send();setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();}, 500)})()`. Not perfect, but do the job ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found :

- Install App "Rest Client For Android"
- paste the URL
- add custom HTTP header "Cache-control: no-cache"

In the response, Varnish (depends on your config) add an http header who says "missed" = response doesn't come from the cache.

Many thanks
Etienne